# React/Redux app not working unless chrome developer tools open?

Tags: django, reactjs, google-chrome, redux, google-chrome-devtools

Pretty much in the title. For some reason things like my redux actions and click handlers only fire reliably when my developer tools are open. I have no idea why this could be happening. It is extremely frustrating. Tested on Firefox and it works perfectly fine. Anybody have any idea why is happening?

Comment: Try restarting your browser?

Comment: Tried that, didn’t work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. Apparently the API calls to my backend needed to have slashes at the end. Firefox added them automatically I guess and Chrome only added them when my dev tools were open. Crazy.